# Django FormView method 'form_valid()' not working when I specify html form action

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, formview

I'm trying to send this form data by POST. When I click on submit it redirects me to the `<form action="{% url 'create-checkout-session' %}"` specified but I never get the email. If I delete the `<action=""` it sends the data by email but of course I'm not getting redirected to the url I want. The thing is that this url is not something I can hardcode since It's generated by Stripe payments and for each request it's a new one, so the success_url of the FormView is not something I can use.

The thing I want to achieve is to get redirected to the form action but at the same time get the form data by email.

This is the form.

```
<form action="{% url 'create-checkout-session' %}" method="POST">
    {{form.name}}
    {{form.surname}}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
    Card Payment
</button>
```

And I'm handling it this way in the view.

```
class checkoutView(UserPassesTestMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'store/checkout.html'
    form_class = userInfoForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('create-checkout-session')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        subject = 'New message from: ' + form.cleaned_data['email']
        message = form.cleaned_data['name']
        recipient_list = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        connection = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
        send_mail(subject, message, recipient_list, connection)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 1):

You made some errors when you send the email. You use `settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER` as `recipient_list`, but this should be a *list* of *recipients*, not the email address from which you want to send items. The `recipient_list` is thus likely a singleton list with `self.request.user` as item. This should also be the *fourth* parameter of `send_mail`, not the third. It is also possible that you should use `form.cleaned_data['email']` instead if that is the receiver that you want to send an email.

For the `connection`, we can make use of `None` to work with the [**`DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL) setting, so we can send an email with:

```
class checkoutView(UserPassesTestMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'store/checkout.html'
    form_class = userInfoForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('create-checkout-session')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        subject = 'New message from: ' + form.cleaned_data['email']
        message = form.cleaned_data['name']
        recipient_list = [request.user.email]
        send_mail(subject, message, None, recipient_list)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I still could send emails even though I had errors in the send_mail(). The problem here is that I'm not getting the email when I have an `action` in the form HTML. If I leave the action to empty string I'm getting the emails.

Comment: @Spaceguy: usually one defines `action={% 'name-of-the-view' %}` to ensure that the correct view is referred. Especially for POST requests that might be useful, since a POST request to the wrong view, can make unwanted changes. A GET is supposed to be "safe", a POST request not.

Comment: I actually did it! `path('create-checkout-session/', createCheckoutSessionView.as_view(), name='create-checkout-session'),` this is the url and this what i wrote in the action `<form action="{% url 'create-checkout-session' %}" method="POST">`

Comment: @Spaceguy: but your view class is named `checkoutView`, not `createCheckoutSessionView`. You thus make a POST request to the wrong view.

Comment: Yep, I get it now, thanks. Still I need a POST request to that view and redirect me to the view `create-checkout-session` Guess that's what success_url is for but I can't use the success_url because as I said that url is generated by the View `create-checkout-session` and it's always a different one.